# calling both GET and POST service calls in same function using angular 2

Tags: angular

How do i call http POST service call after the GET, if response is success.

I have the written the GET call in the following way,

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/login/login.html'
})


export class LoginPage {    
  constructor(private nav: NavController, public http: Http) {
  }

  onLogin(value: string): void { 
    if(this.authForm.valid) {        
      this.http.get('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=1/json')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => {console.log(JSON.stringify(data));},
        err => this.logError(err),
        () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
      );

      this.nav.push(AccountViewPage);
    }
  } 

  logError(err) {
    console.error('There was an error: ' + err);
  }
}
```

sample url for POST:

> https://itunes.apple.com/1/json

```
headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
ignoreAuthModule: 'ignoreAuthModule'
```

Comment: can't do post in subscriber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 **It could be better if you use another Function sucees**  

  onLogin(value: string): void { 
   if(this.authForm.valid) {        
     this.http.get('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=1/json')
     .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
       data => {console.log(JSON.stringify(data));},
       err => this.logError(err),
       () => this.add();
      );

     this.nav.push(AccountViewPage);
  }
  } 

  public add(): void {
  // another service here
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @mayur..that is what i expected..But it will not execute second function until the first response comes right?

Comment: You can call after data the add() or after this ()=>   as it dependency you want after success

Comment: thanks @mayur..one more i am getting error while passing parameters to GET call; Argument of type '{ params: URLSearchParams; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestOptionsArgs'.                          This is my code: let options = new RequestOptions({         
          params: new URLSearchParams('validateUsr=false')
      });

Comment: Just as see it seems me to type miss match but not clear till now just try to send a simple string like let a='apple'; and add this params and check whether it fails