# Angular 2 POST with Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, firefox, angular

I am new to Angular 2 and my application that works fine with IE and chrome. However, when I try in Firefox the post request that calls my PHP script does not work within Firefox.

```
postApplicant(newApplicant: Applicant): Observable<string> {
        let body = `firstName=${newApplicant.firstName}&lastName=${newApplicant.lastName}`;
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
            headers.append('Accept', 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(this.emailUrl, body, options)
                        .map(res =>  <string> res.json())
                        .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

Comment: please, be more accurate, post the error you get

Comment: not clear about issue but can check for refrence http://stackoverflow.com/a/37290319/5868331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the value of your `Accept` header isn't correct. Perhaps it's the reason of your problem on Firefox.

You could try the following:

```
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8');
```

Otherwise, your Angular2 code seems correct...

This article could interest you:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/10/understanding-http-content-negotiation/