# Post call method in ionic2

Tags: http, post, ionic2

New to ionic2 want to know what is post method , where to use, where to write a code???

Here is the sample code

`//ts code`

```
constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
) {
this.signupForm = formBuilder.group({

    firstName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(20), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])]
});
```

`//html code`

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm">
<ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>FIRST NAME</ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="firstName" type="text"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
</form>
```

`-- want to post the signupForm!!`

Comment: Approved Answer can refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37290319/5868331 its an get request use post instead of get

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's keep it short for basic understanding of post method.

`import { Http } from '@angular/http'; import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`

then

```
doPost(someData: any): Observable<any> { 
    this.http.post('auth/login').map(response => {
    return response.json(); 
    });
}
```

then you call it with

`doPost(myData).subscribe(response => console.log(response));`